# variable not working in function (python 3)

Tags: python, function, variables

```
tokens = 100

def double_or_nothing(amount):
  if randint(1, 0) == 1:
    if input("double? ").lower == "yes":
      amount *= 2
      double_or_nothing(amount)
    else:
      tokens += amount
  else:
    tokens -= amount
```

I get an error over "tokens += amount" that says:
[pyflakes] local variable 'tokens' defined in enclosing scope on line 41 referenced before assignment

Comment: One styling issue I noticed is your code seems to be indented with 2 spaces instead of 4, which I believe is more conventional.

Comment: `.lower` should be `.lower()`

Comment: But I believe you'll need to add the line `global tokens` at the top of the function definition to resolve the variable not defined issue

Comment: You haven't given a starting value for `tokens` - that `tokens = 100` outside the function is initializing a global variable, entirely unrelated to the local variable used inside the function.  You either need to move the initialization into the function, or put `global tokens` inside the function so that it refers to the global variable.

Answer (score 0):

You can't modify a variable that lives outside of the function - you can read it, but not modify it.

The cleanest solution would be to return the change in the number tokens instead of manipulating the variable that lives outside the function, and then track the current number of tokens outside of the function itself:

```
from random import randint
tokens = 100

def double_or_nothing(amount):
  if randint(0, 2) == 1:
    if input("double? ").strip().lower() == "yes":
      amount *= 2
      return double_or_nothing(amount)
    else:
      return amount
  else:
    return -amount

while tokens > 0:
  print("You have ", tokens)
  tokens += double_or_nothing(10)
```

Comment: `You can't modify a variable that lives outside of the function` - this statement is clearly false

Comment: for example: `tokens = 0
def run():
    global tokens
    tokens += 1
run()
assert tokens == 1  # this does work`

Comment: Using `global` means that the variable no longer lives outside the function; it has been imported into the function's own scope - i.e. there's a local reference to a variable from the outside scope.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure how a variable would no longer be global if `global` keyword is used. for example I can still access a `tokens` global variable outside of the function scope, even after i modify its value within a function.

Comment: My point is that when you use `global`, you create a *local reference* to a global variable (i.e. the reference has been imported from globals to locals), and you work with the _local_ variable (since it has now been "shadowed" into the scope of the function itself). However, this is nitpicking; you can't change a variable defined outside of the function, unless you do something to change that specifically.  Using `global` or other hacks such as `globals()` is a bad solution, as it makes code far harder to maintain and reason about.

Comment: Ah, I see. This is much useful information that I didn't know before about how `global` worked - appreciate the clarification. I still think it's important for a person new to Python to know about how `global` works, because even though it might not be the best solution, its usage is still quite common. For instance, the `boto3` library uses the `global` keyword in their top level script to set up a default session. There may other well known examples, but that is just one I remember seeing clearly.